# Facebook login button disabled on localhost

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, localhost

I'm testing the sample [Run with Friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/) Google App Engine Facebook app.  When running on localhost:8888, clicking the login button brings up a new small window, which disappears almost instantly, and doesn't actually log in.  How can I test logging into Facebook on localhost?  I saw [this question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5133075/running-facebook-application-on-localhost), but the accepted answer doesn't seem applicable to Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a local Nginx instance in front of dev server. Nginx really easy to configure for proxying reguest from domain like `mylocalapp.dev` to your app.

Configuration looks like:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80; #it's for ipv6
    #listen 80; #for ipv4
    server_name mylocalapp.dev;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

And also, don't use suffix like `.local` for domain, it doesn't work for FB too.

Comment: Is mylocalapp.dev an actual domain that you can configure, or is it a fake domain?

Comment: fake domain, that you can configure in your `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: I'm developing on Windows, sorry I didn't mention that.  Is the code you posted the entire nginx.conf file?  What else do I have to configure on Windows?

Comment: On Windows the file is located in `system` directory (google for full path, I don't remember). My configuration example you have to append to existing `nginx.conf` (or use as a standalone file and include into main config)

Comment: It looks like it's `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows.  Thanks, I'll try this out again now.

Comment: btw, i'm not sure that you should use ipv6 on Window. So try to use `listen 80` intead

Comment: Alright, I managed to get it working without resorting to Nginx.  Thanks for your help anyway, and I may use this later.